# Troubles with generation .dacbac file

Tags: sql, sql-server

The customers set the task to update the database using dacpac. This technology has not been used before. In the process of generating the file, we received a large number of errors. But, to be more precise, the errors are 71564 and 71561. The content is as follows (for example, I will give one message each, so as not to stretch the message):

> Error SQL71564: Error validating element [Indusoft]: The element [Indusoft]  has been orphaned from its login and cannot be deployed.
> Error SQL71561: Error validating element [dbo].[v_SampleReportValue2]: View: [dbo].[v_SampleReportValue2] has an unresolved reference to object [I-LDS RN SNPZ].[dbo].[v_TestResult].
> Error SQL71501: Error validating element [dbo].[v_TTRange]: View: [dbo].[v_TTRange] contains an unresolved reference to an object. Either the object does not exist or the reference is ambiguous because it could refer to any of the following objects: [dbo].[TechTestLimit].[TTRange], [dbo].[TTBoundaryPoint].[TTRange], [dbo].[TTRange].[TechTestVerId], [dbo].[TTRange].[TTRange] or [dbo].[TTRangeItem].[TTRange].

Please tell me what you need to do to solve this problem

Comment: Hi, can you run select * from [dbo].[v_TTRange] to check that's the view is OK? Can you check that inner query of a view is OK and each column has source alias?

Comment: For `SQL71564` see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38857692/error-sql71564-when-migrating-to-azure) post.
For `SQL71561` see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12161392/using-ssdt-how-do-i-resolve-sql71561-errors-when-i-have-a-view-that-references) post.
For `SQL71501` see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28759810/sql71501-how-to-get-rid-of-this-error) post.

Comment: Adding that using dacpacs are problematic when invalid objects exist in the database (e.g. views referencing tables/columns that no longer exist). Depending on your use cases, consider VS database projects, source control, and CI/CD processes can help avoid such problems.